# Grouping DISTINCT SQL results into objects

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to combine data from two tables (the first being a shipment details table with data for a single shipment per row, the other a table that tracks transactions made against shipments) to build a view that shows me the product data for a given shipment.

My current attempt to get the data looks like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    sd.erp_order AS shipment_id, 
    th.product_code, 
    th.lot
FROM transaction_history th
JOIN shipment_detail sd
    ON sd.shipment_id = th.reference_id
    AND sd.item = th.item
WHERE th.transaction_type = '1'
    AND sd.erp_order in ('1111', '1112')
```

which returns my data in the following format:

```
|shipment_id|product_code|lot|
|       1111|   PRODUCT_A| 1A|
|       1111|   PRODUCT_B| 2B|
|       1112|   PRODUCT_A| 1A|
|       1112|   PRODUCT_B| 3B|
```

This is great, but now I need to organize it so that when it goes through my API (I'm using Django), it the lot code and the product code are grouped together in their own object, and then all the products are listed under the relevant shipment:

```json
[
  {
    "shipment_id": '1111',
    "products": [
      {
        "product_code": "PRODUCT_A",
        "lot": "1A",
      },
      {
        "product_code": "PRODUCT_B",
        "lot": "2B",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I'm not quite sure how to do it. Is this something that can be done with SQL, or will I have to do it with Python?

I also recognize that I should be able to get this kind of data from existing tables, but this is a siloed database that I cannot modify, and I'm told by the supporting team that this is the best place to get the data I need.

Comment: What's your RDBMS?

Comment: They use SQL Server for their DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', SomeModel.objects.raw(query), fields=('id', 'name', 'parent'))
```

[Serialisation Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/serialization/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was quite clear enough in my question. The issue isn't getting the data from the SQL result to a JSON format, it's grouping the product information under each shipment. I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to generate JSON data in the DB and then convert data to JSON in python:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sd.erp_order AS shipment_id, 
    products.product_code, 
    products.lot
FROM shipment_detail sd
JOIN transaction_history products
    ON sd.shipment_id = products.reference_id
    AND sd.item = products.item
WHERE products.transaction_type = '1'
    AND sd.erp_order in ('1111', '1112')
FOR JSON AUTO
```

for more information read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).

Sample running in MSSQL:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, it's not the converting to JSON that's the issue, is adjusting the data so instead of just returning rows of` id, product_code,lot`, it returns the grouped `product_code,lot` under the relevant shipment. (so in this example, there would only be two items in the base array instead of 4).

Comment: @LoganWaite the JSON you put in question is your expected output?

Comment: Yes. You'll notice it's different than what the returned DB rows are. I did try adding that `FOR JSON AUTO` at the end of my query like you showed, but all it did was return a `NULL` value, so I'm not sure what was supposed to happen there.

Comment: @LoganWaite what's your sql server version?

Comment: I believe it's SQL Server 2016

Comment: @LoganWaite I created a sample query for it and I updated the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246896/discussion-between-logan-waite-and-farshid-shekari).